# How can I return Apache's HttpResponse within Spring's HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, proxy, httpresponse

I have an endpoint using Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/hello"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getContent(@RequestParam(value = "url", required = true) String url)
```

I would like this to return the exact same response I would get if I send a GET to `url`. I'm using the Apache library to do my GET, which returns me a `CloseableHttpResponse`. How do I return this response as my endpoint's response? My current code copies this response, which is not what I want. I would directly like to return the `CloseableHttpResponse`. The reason I want to do this is because some websites have really huge data, and I would like to avoid having to copy those in place.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/hello"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getContent(@RequestParam(value = "url", required = true) String url, HttpServletResponse response)
     CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = useApacheLibraryAndSendGetToUrl(url);
     for (Header header : httpResponse.getAllHeaders()) {
         response.addHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
     }
     response.setStatus(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
     return EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a custom `HttpMessageConverter` for the `CloseableHttpResponse` type, which would allow you to simply return `@ResponseBody CloseableHttpResponse`.

See [*Mapping the response body with the @ResponseBody annotation*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) for details.

Comment: Be careful of course to actually close the `CloseableHttpResponse` at the appropriate time.

Comment: Also, it may provide better performance or memory usage to directly copy the `CloseableHttpResponse` entity's `InputStream` to the `HttpServletResponse`'s `OutputStream`, rather than to use `EntityUtils.toString` to first copy the response into a string.

Comment: If I use a converter, wouldn't that still be the same thing I'm doing here, where I have to copy data from CloseableHttpResponse and convert that to some form of response in Spring? I forgot to the mention the issue I'm running into is some websites have really huge header data, and I would like to avoid having to copy these.